# Creating a dynamic atom theme with pywal?

Tags: css, less, atom-editor

I'm trying to write an atom theme. However, it will not be static. I want to use imported css from pywal to change how atom looks depending on the color scheme of the rest of the desktop at that given moment. I am able to import the colors from the pywal cache, and use them as css colors. I can even assign them to less variables. However, when I try to use a function such as darken, I get the error `error evaluating function 'darken': color.toHSL is not a function`

I had concluded it was due to the import settings, so I tried using the (less) keyword in my import for the css file. When I did so, it said it could not find the file, so (in order to test if I was at least right about the import settings), I copied the pywal css file into the styles directory and changed the filename in import accordingly. This led me back to square one, as I started receiving the same error. An example of my attempts are below.

Relevant code:

~/.cache/wal/colors.css (aka "tempcolors.css"):

```
/* CSS variables
Generated by 'wal' */
:root {
    --wallpaper: url("/home/regular/wallpapers/current/image.jpg");

    /* Special */
    --background: #0a0b10;
    --foreground: #d5c5a8;
    --cursor: #d5c5a8;

    /* Colors */
    --color0: #0a0b10;
    --color1: #483E45;
    /* ... */
    --color15: #d5c5a8;
}
```

colors.less:

```
// These colors are specific to the theme. Do not use in a package!

//@import (less) url('file:///home/[MYUSERNAME]/.cache/wal/colors.css'); // this stopped working when I added (less)
@import (less) "tmpcolors.css";

@very-light-gray: #c5c8c6;
@light-gray: #969896;
/* the rest of the standard colors */

@background: var(--background);
@foreground: var(--foreground);

@color-1: var(--color1);
@color-2: var(--color2);
/* ... */
@color-15: var(--color15);
```

Here's the section in base.less where I tried to use my custom colors:

```
atom-text-editor {
    /* ... */
.gutter {
    background-color: @color-7; //works
    background-color: darken(@color-7, 25%); //doesn't work
    background-color: darken(@red, 25%); //works
```

Can someone help me? Is what I'm trying to do possible?

P.S. Please let me know if you need more info